# First [Monday] of the month, Second [Thursday] of the month, etc. Delphi

Tags: delphi, datetime

Using Delphi, I need a function to evaluate the current date and see if it's, for example, the Third Sunday of the month, etc.

In pseudocode:

```
function IsFirst(const CurrentDateTime: TDateTime; const Day: Word): Boolean;
/// Day can be 1-7 (monday to sunday)
begin
  Result:= ??
end;
```

Another function would be needed to calculate the Second, Third, Forth and Last of the month. DateUtils seems to have nothing like that. Any ideas?

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Your function has no result type, your intention is not clear from the code or from the text of your question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This function is what you need:

```
function IsFirst(const DateTime: TDateTime; const Day: Word): Boolean;
begin
  Result := (DayOfTheWeek(DateTime)=Day) and 
    InRange(DayOfTheMonth(DateTime), 1, 7);
end;
```

The equivalent function for the second occurrence is:

```
function IsSecond(const DateTime: TDateTime; const Day: Word): Boolean;
begin
  Result := (DayOfTheWeek(DateTime)=Day) and 
    InRange(DayOfTheMonth(DateTime), 8, 14);
end;
```

I'm sure you can fill out the details for third, fourth and fifth. You may prefer to write a single general function like this:

```
function IsNth(const DateTime: TDateTime; const Day: Word; 
  const N: Integer): Boolean;
var
  FirstDayOfWeek, LastDayOfWeek: Integer;
begin
  LastDayOfWeek := N*7;
  FirstDayOfWeek = LastDayOfWeek-6;
  Result := (DayOfTheWeek(DateTime)=Day) and 
    InRange(DayOfTheMonth(DateTime), FirstDayOfWeek, LastDayOfWeek);
end;
```

Answer (score 4):

This can be done using simple math.

Get the `DayOfTheWeek` and divide the `DayOf` by seven.

Comment: Yeah, he probably means `mod`.

Comment: I meant `DayOf` which should give the same result as `DayOfTheMonth`, I should have separated this into two sentences. The point was that you can do it using simple math. Davids answer is just fine.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - I wasn't pointing to the answer, just the "divide by" part. I cowardly refuse to code anything related to date calculation after seeing the internals of the `DateTime` Perl modules.